# How to add icons and tooltip on react-select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am trying add fontawesome icon and tooltip on react-select component options. Below image i am trying to achieve

[image]

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const websiteFilterFiedsOptions = [
    {value: '', label: 'Search and select website activity'},
    {value: 'page_visited', label: 'Page Visited'},
    {value: 'form_submitted', label: 'Form Submitted'}
]

export default class Website extends Component { 

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedFilter: ''
        }
    }

    filterSelectedData = function(data) {

    }

    render() {
        return <div className="form-group">
                    <h6 className="website_filter"><b>Filters</b></h6>
                    <div className="location-search field-width filed_width_custom">
                        <Select
                            value={this.state.selectedFilter}
                            onChange={(e) => this.filterSelectedData(e)}
                            options={ websiteFilterFiedsOptions }
                            placeholder="Search and select website activity"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the component as shown below, added it for only one option for demo purpose, you can style it in your way.

Even you can use a reusable component to generate  label, since label accepts a node.

I hope this will solve the issue.

```
{
    value: "page_visited",
    label: (
      <>
        <span style={{ paddingRight: "5px" }}>Page Visited</span>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="info" title={"Page Visited Option"} />
      </>
    )
  },
```

Entire Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { fab } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import { faInfo, faCoffee } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

library.add(fab, faInfo, faCoffee);

const websiteFilterFiedsOptions = [
  { value: "", label: "Search and select website activity" },
  {
    value: "page_visited",
    label: (
      <>
        <span style={{ paddingRight: "5px" }}>Page Visited</span>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="info" title={"Page Visited Option"} />
      </>
    )
  },
  { value: "form_submitted", label: "Form Submitted" }
];

export default class Website extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedFilter: ""
    };
  }

  filterSelectedData = function(data) {};

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <h6 className="website_filter">
          <b>Filters</b>
        </h6>
        <div className="location-search field-width filed_width_custom">
          <Select
            value={this.state.selectedFilter}
            onChange={e => this.filterSelectedData(e)}
            options={websiteFilterFiedsOptions}
            placeholder="Search and select website activity"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Website />, rootElement);
```

Working [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-shirley-thngm)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this way by making your own component and object with the icon values.

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3480

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get reference from this https://codesandbox.io/s/8ln4vnr1v2?from-embed

Answer (score 0):

In my case also "placeholder" wouldn't work, so first I replace my select with select component of **"antd"** then try placeholder and it worked well.

---

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Select} from "antd";

function DropdownFilter(props) {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(props.data)
    if (props.data !== undefined)
        setData(props.data);
}, props.data);

return (

    <Select
        onChange={props.onChange}
        placeholder={"Tooltip or Hint Text"}
    >
        {
            data?.map((item) => {
                return <option value={item.title}>{item.title}</option>
            })
        }
    </Select>

)
 };


export default DropdownFilter;
```